# Nintex Flexi Task Escalation Feature

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

We're using Nintex 2013, and I have a flexi task set up so that reminders are sent every 10 business days, 3 reminders total. On the escalation screen, it says "Time to Escalation" and then has the days/hours/minutes fields. Is the time calculated from the end of the reminders, or from the original task assigned date? The documentation says, "Escalation occurs after all reminders have been sent and the specified "Time to escalation" has elapsed." That's a little ambiguous to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is time to escalation is calculated from the original assigned date, and based on the number of reminders and task between each reminder. When the task is added the timer list the counters begin. The number of reminders + the time between each reminder drives the time to escalation.